# File Stream program not showing the .exe window

Tags: c++, exe, filestream

Recently I made a simple C++ program that reads and writes class objects using File Streams write() and read() in Visual C++ 2010 express. The program compiles fine, but when I go to the .exe file and open it, it closes in a jiffy. I have used '_getch()' at the end, but I still have this problem.

I have a Turbo C++ background (blame my school).

Here's the code by the way.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;

struct Student 
{
    char name[40];
    char grade;
    float marks;
public:
    void getdata();
    void display();
};

void Student :: getdata(void)
{
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin.getline(name, 40);
    cout << "Enter grade: ";
    cin >> grade;
    cout << "Enter marks: ";
    cin >> marks;
}

void Student :: display(void)
{
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Grade: " << grade << endl;
    cout << "Marks: " << marks << endl;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Student arts[3];
    fstream filin;
    filin.open("Stu.dat", ios::in|ios::out);
    if (!filin)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file! \n";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Enter details for 3 students: ";
    for (int i =0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        arts[i].getdata();
        filin.write((char *) & arts[i], sizeof (arts[i]));
    }
    filin.seekg(0);
    cout << "The contents of stu.dat are shown below: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        filin.read((char *) & arts[i], sizeof (arts[i]));
        arts[i].display();
    }
    filin.close();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To view the output before the window closes put in this little function somewhere: `void doExit() { _getch(); }` and add `atexit(doExit);` to the very top of your `main` function. Alternatively, you can run your program from the command line rather than through the IDE to keep the output displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a `_getch();` here

```
    cout << "Cannot open file! \n";
    _getch();
    return 1;
```

Comment: But it only shows `Cannot open file!` in the .exe window. It is not supposed to do that.